# NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Tags: python, subprocess, nameerror

I'm trying to make a rng from this website: http://jamesdotcom.com/?p=417.
However when I run the following code:

```
captureImage = subprocess.Popen(
   [
       "fswebcam", "-r", "356x292", "-d", "/dev/video0", 
       "static.jpg", "--skip", "10"
   ], 
   stdout=devNull, stderr=devNull)
captureImage.communicate()
```

I get the following error message:

```
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you imported it first?

```
import subprocess
captureImage = subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam", ...)
```

[Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is included in Python standard library since Python 2.4. It should not be necessary to install it.

Comment: I imported it and it says NameError: name 'devNull' is not defined. What should I do?

Comment: @NeilSehgal Please look at the full source code at the end of that blogpost you linked. There is `devNull = open('/dev/null', 'w')`.